# Django Tables2 Filter

Tags: django, filter

I am trying to display a table with filter using Django tables 2 and crispy forms.

I have the following files:

**filter.py**

```
import django_filters
from .models import Poste
class PosteFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    status = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    address = django_filters.CharFilter(name='address', lookup_expr='icontains')
    atualizado_em  = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

class Meta:
    model = Poste
    fields = {'id', 'status', 'address', 'atualizado_em',}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Poste
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, ButtonHolder, Submit

class PosteListFormHelper(FormHelper):
    model = Poste
    form_tag = False
    form_style = 'inline'
    layout = Layout(
        'id',
        'status',
        'address',
        'atualizado_em',
        Submit('submit', 'Filtrar'),
    )
```

**table.py**

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Poste

class PosteTable(tables.Table):
class Meta:
    model = Poste
    # add class="paleblue" to <table> tag
    attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
    fields = ('id', 'status', 'address', 'atualizado_em')
    per_page: 25
```

As a result, I get this:

[image]

What I want is:

1. exclude the word "contains" in the label
2. have the filter form fields inline

I tried many ways to do that without success.

Comment: Changing the label is a separate issue from changing the form layout, so this might be better as two different questions. If you tried many ways without success, it would be good to see what you tried, so that people do not suggest things that do not work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you can set the label by setting `label` in the `CharFilter`:

```
class PosteFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Id')
    status = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Status')
    ...
```

It looks as if you could also change the [`FILTERS_VERBOSE_LOOKUPS`](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/settings.html#filters-verbose-lookups) setting, although the docs warn that it's an advanced setting and subject to change.

```
from django_filters.conf import DEFAULTS

def FILTERS_VERBOSE_LOOKUPS():
    verbose_lookups = DEFAULTS['VERBOSE_LOOKUPS'].copy()
    verbose_lookups['icontains'] = ''  # Don't add any extra text like 'contains'
    return verbose_lookups
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine solving the first part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I use `FormHelper` to make the form inline

```
class UnitFilterFormHelper(FormHelper):
    form_method = 'GET'
    form_style = 'inline'
    form_show_labels = False
    label_class = 'col-md-1'
    field_class = 'col-md-11'
    layout = Layout(
        HTML('<hr>'),
        Row(
            Column('branch', css_class="col-md-10"),
            Column(Submit('submit', _('Apply Filter')), css_class="col-md-2"),
            # css_class="form-inline",
        ),
    )
```